# Angular JS - How to find the element in DOM having the xpath?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, dom, browser, firefox-developer-tools

How can I use xpath instead of id to find the element in DOM. I know that for id I can use: `$("#id")[0]`.

I use `$("#id")[0]` inside Developer mode in browser in order to get the element by id to see what methods (like `.getText()`, `innerHTML` or others) am I able to use for the element. I want to know how to do this by XPATH

Thanks in advance

Comment: I use this inside Developer mode in browser in order to get the element by id to see what methods (like .getText() , innerHTML or others) am I able to use for the element. I want to know how to do this by XPATH

Comment: AFAIK, there is no embedded methods in `Javascript` to use `XPath`

Comment: @Andersson Actually, there is a method: $x("xpath")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Firefox console you can find (and explore) the element like this:

```
$x("//button[@id='myButton']")
```

But if you want to call a function on the element, you have to call it like this:

`$x("//button[@id='myButton']")[0].click()`

because there is always an array of elements returned (provided that the element is present and the first one in the array).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. I found out the answer. It can be done with:

```
$x("xpath")
```